# Correct adding element to array of objects in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects that I get from API call like this:

```
            new Promise((resolve) => {
            Kit.getSamples(FirstSample, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return resolve([]);
                }
                const newData = results.map(item => { return { ...item, name: 'FirstItem' } });
                this.setState({
                    ActivityItem: newData
                })
            })
```

My date is added correctly. But then, I need to do another call to API, and add other values to the array, but with a different name.

```
            Kit.getSamples(SecondSample, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return resolve([]);
                }
                const newData = results.map(item => { return { ...item, name: 'SecondItem' } });
                this.setState({ ActivityItem: [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...[newData]]})
```

But instead of proper adding to the array, I get an new array inside my array like this:

```
[{"name": "FirstItem", "quantity": 11, "tracked": false}, 
{"name": "FirstItem", "quantity": 21, "tracked": true},
[{"distance": 0.310685596118667, "name": "SecondItem", "tracked": false}]]
```

I wonder if there is a way to add "SecondItem" without having another array inside?

Answer (score 1):

`newData` is already an array once you obtain it by mapping over results, you don't need to wrap it within `[]` before using spread syntax while setting state

```
this.setState({ ActivityItem: [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData]})
```

Answer (score 0):

`...[newData]` is wrapped in an array, so, the result will be inside an array.

Try removing the brackets, like this: `...newData`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the following line

```
this.setState({ ActivityItem: [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...[newData]]})
```

with this line

```
this.setState({ ActivityItem: [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData]})
```